# Get last 5 day record excluding Weekend days?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to extract records from table inserted in last 5 working days  on Oracle SQL
I'm unable to exclude Sunday and Saturday from this(as they're coming into consideration)

```
Select * from xyz where xdate=:businessDate - 5
```

Here `businessDate` (yyyymmdd format) is value taken as a parameter

Any pointers would greatly  be valued and appreciated .

Comment: Date=. I don't think that could bei what you are searching

Comment: Sorry I didn't understood what you're saying

Comment: `Select * from xyz where xdate=:businessDate - 5 and to_char(:businessDate,'DAY') NOT LIKE 'S%'`

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja  thank you for your quick answer. I want to highlight businessDate is in format of yyyymmdd format. Will that work in your provided solution?

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja and when this program gets installed in an oracle db in france, where sunday is "dimanche", and the logic falls apart?

Comment: @Caius Jard .

Comment: If db was installed else where i will develop a translator to_standard_english_format to run this

Comment: You seem to be forgetting that stackoverflow has an international audience, and we aren't just here to answer this guy's problem, but to provide robust advice to all future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM xyz
WHERE 
  xdate >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 7 --last 7 days AND 
  TRUNC (xdate) - TRUNC (xdate, 'IW') NOT IN (5,6) --not sat or sun
```

Take the last 7 days data, and remove any data from saturday or sunday.

`TRUNC (xdate) - TRUNC (xdate, 'IW')` returns a value between 0 and 6 inclusive. 0 is monday. This is not affected by NLS date settings because it uses the same region setting in both truncs, so regardless if the week starts on sunday or monday in your country, the result of the calc is the same

In any given 7 day period you have 5 week days and 2 weekend days

Note that this query assumes the table has no future dated data. If it does put a restriction that xdate must be less than sysdate

Comment: Thanks @caius jard for your valuable suggestions. I would love to try it out and let you know whether it's working or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an oracle expert but this could also work

```
SELECT *
FROM xyz
WHERE xdate IN (:businessDate - 1, :businessDate - 2, :businessDate - 3, :businessDate - 4, :businessDate - 5, :businessDate - 6, :businessDate - 7)  AND MOD(TO_CHAR(xdate, 'J'), 7) + 1 NOT IN (6, 7);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
select * from xyz 
 where xdate >= TO_DATE( :businessDate, 'yyyymmdd' ) - 7
   and to_char( xdate, 'DAY' ) not in ( 'SAT', 'SUN' )
```

That's assuming you're working in an English database. That should give you the past 7 days worth, but exclude weekends.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do something like the following:

```
WITH cteData AS (SELECT TO_DATE(:BUSINESSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') AS BUSINESS_DATE FROM DUAL)
SELECT * 
  FROM XYZ x
  CROSS JOIN cteData d
  WHERE TRUNC(x.XDATE) BETWEEN d.BUSINESS_DATE - 7
                           AND d.BUSINESS_DATE AND
        TRUNC(x.XDATE) - TRUNC(x.XDATE, 'IW') <= 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out the weekend day i.e. Sunday or Saturday by using 'DAY' format in format_date function e.g.

```
IF FORMAT_DATE(Date,'DAY')='SATURDAY' then date-1

IF FORMAT_DATE(Date,'DAY')='SUNDAY' then date-2
```

You would get only 5 days record